# Stage appears as success immediately, even though it's still running in Jenkins declarative parallel job

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I've got parallel Jenkins stages in a declarative pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('parallel') {
            parallel {
                stage('one') {
                    steps {
                        sleep 20
                        echo "Done"
                    }
                }
                stage('two') {
                    steps {
                        sleep 20
                        echo "Done"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It does work, but the Stage View is a bit misleading while it's running. The first stage, "one", seems reasonable, but the second, "two", appears to complete immediately in 0ms.

[image: Jenkins Staged view of two parallel jobs where it looks like the first is in progress, but the second has completed in 0ms]

When it's done, it looks fine, and the times finish up as what I expect (other than maybe the parent "parallel" stage... but to me that's a minor thing)

[image: Jenkins Stage view of two parallel jobs where both have completed in 20s]

How can I make the Stage View more accurately show what stages are running while they're running?